# simple_form display current value on collection_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form

I am using **simple_form** and have an array of values stored in the model. I want the index to the stored in the table, with the value displayed on the selection drop-down.

So far I have this:

**model**

```
PRIMER_TM_FORMULA_OPTIONS = ["Breslauer et al. 1986", "SantaLucia 1998"]
```

**form**

```
  <%= f.input :primer_tm_formula, :collection => 0..Primer3Batch::PRIMER_TM_FORMULA_OPTIONS.length, :label_method => lambda { |i| Primer3Batch::PRIMER_TM_FORMULA_OPTIONS[i] }, label: 'Thermo Parms', input_html: {class: 'input-large'}, selected: :primer_tm_formula  %>
```

It's mostly working, but after an update, and when the form is refreshed, the page always displays the value at the 0 index of the array, even though the correct value is stored in the database.

Also, it seems to be this code is quite convoluted. As part of the answer, if there is a more concise way to achieve  the same goal please let me know.

**FINAL CODE**

Based on the accepted answer, the final code in the view is this, for anyone else trying to do the same thing.

```
<%= f.input :primer_tm_formula,
    collection: 0..Primer3Batch::PRIMER_TM_FORMULA_OPTIONS.length,
    label_method: lambda { |i| Primer3Batch::PRIMER_TM_FORMULA_OPTIONS[i] },
    label: 'Thermo Parms',
    input_html: {class: 'input-large'},
    selected: Primer3Batch::PRIMER_TM_FORMULA_OPTIONS[f.object.primer_tm_formula] %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the stored value by referencing the form object: f.object.primer_tm_formula and setting it like so: selected: f.object.primer_tm_formula

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I couldn't get it to work. Did you mean selected: f.object.primer_tm_formula (not value)

Comment: Yes, sorry for the typo I meant primer_tm_formula

Comment: No I am afraid it is doing the same thing - displaying the 0 index value, regardless of what is in the database.

Comment: What is being stored in the db? You could print this and verify the correct things are stored. If you are storing theindex value use that in conjunction with your constant like so selected: Primer3Batch::PRIMER_TM_OPTIONS_FORMULA_OPTIONS[f.object.primer_tm_formula]

Comment: No luck. I've added some text to the question. I think I will try reloading the form instance variable.

Comment: If you are doing form_for @some_instance_var you could always reference that one?!

Comment: I found it, thanks for all your help. I'd vote you up twice if I could. I had marked the field attr_accessible and then later overridden to attr_reader